# Azure Media Service Bearer Token to access VOD

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-authentication

I am building a VOD service using Azure Media Service.

I have added Authorization policy as "Token" and have entered issuer, scope and primary verification key.

I am unable to get the correct Bearer Token to access content in Assets.

I have tried the following methods:

1. **Using Azure PHP SDK**:
   I created a token template and used this function in the SDK: TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer::generateTestToken
2. **https://media.ams.ext.azure.com/api/Utils/IssueToken**: Created a form to send type, issuer, scope, primaryVerificationKey, secondaryVerificationKey to this url and obtained token.

The tokens obtained with both the methods do not work. When i try to play the video, i get "Authorization failed" message.

Please help me how to obtain the correct token?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this in steps:
(Assume you are using AMS v2 API. Please let me know if that is not the case.)

1. First please do not add any RequiredClaims for now when setting up content protection (ContentKeyAuthorizationPolicyRestriction) and we can add that after we get basics working. Use the following values in your code for configuring content protection
   For issuer, use: https://sts.windows.net/51641c40-ad65-4736-88fc-2f0e10072d85/
   For audience, use: 29635cdc-ca9a-48b7-b242-05a31810e8c9
   Use symmetric verification key: C4D3E9FB-2533-4061-9892-2B8F58A1AECB
   (Don't worry what these values are for now. We will replace them by yours later on.)
2. For now, do not use your own custom Secure Token Service (STS). Instead use the one I hosted here: https://openidconnectweb.azurewebsites.net/DRMTool/Jwt (choose Custom STS with Symmetric Key).
3. Use this JWT token in your player for playback test. Or you can also use my test player here https://openidconnectweb.azurewebsites.net/AMTestPlayer which allows you to paste in your JWT under player_settings.

After we make this work, we then move on to using your STS (Secure Token Service). Use the same value as above for issuer, audience and symmetric key.

After we make your STS work, we can then move on to the cases you want such as

- Use asymmetric key (x509 cert),
- Adding required claims,
- Using your own issuer, audience,

So for now let's go step by step and be precise at each step. Hopefully this approach would help you isolating/troubleshooting with multiple moving parts: AMS config, AMS license authorization, STS, player/JWT, claims.

Good luck,
William

Comment: Hi William. Thanks for the help but i am unable to make this work. Here's what i did. I updated my Key/license authorization policy to match the one you said. But there was no option to add Symmetric key so i tried to add it in Primary Verification key. But it gave me an error. https://ibb.co/bAVRa8

Then i tried to base64 the symmetric key and enter it. Then i opened the second utl you shared to obtain STS and copied in my player. But the video does not play with this setting. Can you please help how to use symmetric key here. I also tried the test player you shared

Comment: Hi Vitul, if you are using AMSE tool instead of code, you need to convert the GUID to Base64 string. You may use the following tool to convert the GUID to Base64: https://openidconnectweb.azurewebsites.net/DRMTool (select "GUID to Basse64" in the dropdown and replace the content in the textarea by the GUID before clicking OK button).